# Creating an operational menu in python

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, python-3.x, while-loop

1) I have this code so far for while loop but I want to loop it only 12 times:

```
print ("Please enter the 12 monthly figures")
input ("Enter a value in the range 0 to 300:")
```

I have tried a for loop but it didn't operate

2) I want to create a menu of my code and so far I have this:

```
print ("Please choose one of the following options:")

ans=True
while ans:
    print ("""
    0. Quit
    1. Work out and display the total
    3. Work out and display the mean 
    4. Work out and display the standard deviation
    5. Work out and display the median 
    6. Work out and display the lowest and second lowest
    7. Work out and display the 3 month 
    8. Work out and display the months 
    9. Work out display  level
    """)
```

But i want to let the user to pick one

Comment: What's your current code?

Answer (score 0):

There's evidently no switch/case loop for Python, so one thing you can do is build some if statements. If you're using 2.7 you'll use raw_input for user input, and if it's 3.x you'll just use input.

```
if input == 0:
    print ("You picked zero\n")
    ...
```

So on. Also, I think if you put int(input) or whatever you assigned your input to, it'll work, because input takes a string, so you have to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `range()` with a for loop, for example:

```
for i in range(0, 12):
    print(i)
```

2) You can use a series of `if` and `elif` statements for multiple possible values, for example:

```
if a == 0:
    print("something")

elif a == 1:
    print("something else")

elif a == 2:
    print("another something")
```

What these do is, first it checks if the first statement is True, then if its not True it goes to the next statement till there are either no statements left or one of the statements is True.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def get_monthly_rainfall_figures():
    rainfall_figures = []
    print("Please enter the 12 monthly rainfall figures")
    for month in range(12):
        in_ = int(input("Enter a value (0-300): "))
        if 0 <= in_ <= 300:
            rainfall_figures.append(in_)
        else:
            # handle invalid input
    return rainfall_figures
```

and

```
def menu():
    print ("""
0. Quit
1. Work out and display the total
3. Work out and display the mean 
4. Work out and display the standard deviation
5. Work out and display the median 
6. Work out and display the lowest and second lowest
7. Work out and display the 3 month 
8. Work out and display the months 
9. Work out display level
""")
    user_in = input(">>")
    responses = {"0": quit_func,
                 "1": total_func,
                 "3": mean_func,
                ...etc...}
    # where quit_func, total_func, etc are functions that do the described
    # action
    # This design pattern is known as a hash table, and is very idiomatic
    # in Python. In other languages you might use a switch/case block.
    try:
        responses[user_in]()
    except KeyError:
        # handle invalid input
```